# Access JS variable in HTML file via export (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, intellij-idea, socket.io

I am trying to gain access to a variable on the click on a bootstrap button in an HTML file.

Here is my app.js code exporting the variable using exports.

```
var express = require('express'),                                           // Require express functionality
    app = express(),                                                        // Create variable called app and use the express functionality
    server = require('http').createServer(app),                             // Require http functionality, then create server (app variable)
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),                               // Create IO variable to listen to server, while requiring socket.io functionality
    userNames = ['J'],                                                      // Array for usernames
    rooms = [];                                                             // Array for different chatrooms

server.listen(3000);                                                        // Listen on PORT 3000
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

exports.name = userNames;
```

And here is my HTML code with an embedded script in the body. I have tried taking out the `var app = require('./app.js');` and `alert("test");` does work, but as soon as I enter add the line `var app = require('./app.js');`, my program freezes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="http://www.corchurch.org/_assets/css/images/logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="usernameBox" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <input id="passwordBox" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <button id="loginButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = require('./app.js');
        var $loginButton = $('#loginButton');
        $loginButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test");
            alert(app.name[0]);
        });
    </script>
</body>
<footer class="footer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>&copy; 2015 COR Church - Developed by Jerrell Jones</center>
</footer>

</html>
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 on Win7 x64.

Below is my **packages.json** file as well.

```
{
  "name": "CORChat",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "COR Web Chat",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "",
    "express": "",
    "bootstrap": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: This of course happens because in the browser, `require` is undefined. I would instead set up a route on the server that returns the values you're looking for.

Comment: I know this is late, but thanks @KevinB !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you, that you cannot do it this way, because of very simple sever/client concept.

Your (index).html or whatever runs in the client environment in the browser.
Your node.js code runs on the server.

You are creating an server which is running on http://localhost:3000

if you are using express, you can create a route

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Jarrell');
});
```

then run your server script

> node server.js

and access the content from the browser with http://localhost:3000/users